# C# Regex Expression to extract field name and values in SQL Condition

Tags: regex, regex-group

Consider following 2 SQL conditions.

1.) `AssetView.[PROPTYPE] NOT IN ('B15/30','SFD','SFA')`

2.) `AssetView.[FICO] IN (500,600,700)`

I want to break this SQL using RegEx so that I can have table name, field name, function type and field values into 4 different parts.

e.g.

- Table Name - AssetView
- Field Name - PROPTYPE
- Function - NOT IN
- Field Values (Together or separate): B15/30, SFD, SFA

Here is the regex I tried (https://rubular.com/r/WGiyz0oGrooyiA) but I am not able to split TableName, Field Name and Function type into its own group.

```
(.*?)[^=]['(]+(.*?)[')]
```

Comment: Try for example `(\w+)\.\[(\w+)\]\s*(\w+(?: \w+)*) \(([^)\n]+)\)` https://rubular.com/r/qQ13pkCBDztxHv

Comment: @Thefourthbird, Thanks a lot for pointing me in right direction. I was not escaping some of the characters when I was playing with my Regex. I have changed the regex slightly to make it work when there is no parentheses or condition uses "=" instead of "IN" functions. Here is the one that works for me. Sorry, I am not good at formatting.  (\w+)\.[\[]?(\w+)[\]]?\s*([=]*[\w]*(?:\s\w+)*) \(?([^)\n]*)\)?

Comment: I have just posted an answer. Does that work for you?

Comment: @Thefourthbird, can you post your message as answer instead of a posting it as a comment? I would like to accept it as an answer. I wish the regex could be shorten buy it works for me. Not sure why my question was down voted twice. :-(

Comment: I have posted it with some explanations.

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern `(.*?)[^=]['(]+(.*?)[')]` you make use of a character classes `['(]` and `[')]` which match any of the listed and can also first match an opening `'` and then a closing `)`

For your example data, you might use:

```
(\w+)\.\[(\w+)\] +(\w+(?: \w+)*) +\(([^)\n]+)\)
```

- `(\w+)` Capture 1+ word chars in group 1
- `\.` Match a dot
- `\[(\w+)\] +` Capture 1+ word chars between square brackets in group 2 and 1+ spaces
- `(\w+(?: \w+)*) +` Capture 1+ word chars followed by repeating 0+ times matching a space and 1+ word chars in group 3 and 1+ spaces
- `\(([^)\n]+)\)` Capture 1+ times not a closing parenthesis or newline between parenthesis in group 4

[Rubular regex](https://rubular.com/r/iDnnaejDYfwiMh) | [.NET regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cw%2b%29%5c.%5c%5b%28%5cw%2b%29%5c%5d+%2b%28%5cw%2b%28%3f%3a+%5cw%2b%29*%29+%2b%5c%28%28%5b%5e%29%5cn%5d%2b%29%5c%29&i=AssetView.%5bPROPTYPE%5d+IN+%28%27B15%2f30%27%2c%27SFD%27%2c%27SFA%27%29%0d%0aAssetView.%5bPROPTYPE%5d+NOT+IN+%28%27B15%2f30%27%2c%27SFD%27%2c%27SFA%27%29) *(click on the Table tab)*

If you want to allow more characters to match than `\w` you could extend that using a character class.

For example if you also want to allow a hyphen and a space use `[\w-]+` or if you want to match all between the brackets you could make use of a negating character class, for example `\[([^\]]+)\]`